# GetAsyncKeyState and ofstream

Tags: c++

Hi i am new to C++ and i were looking for function GetAsyncKeyState and i did a small app to get "A" and "B" Keys if pressed in a file named log.txt and it works fine but i have a Question:

i added  endl; in each if statement so it is end the line and go to the second line and add the next letter, but when i remove the endl; it didn't put any letters >> ( i removed the endl; as i want all letters to be in the same line )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    ofstream logfile("log.txt", ios::out | ios::ate | ios::app);

    while (true)
    {
        Sleep (100);
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x41))
            logfile << "a" << endl;
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x42))
            logfile << "b" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`endl` does two things.  It puts a newline character in the output stream, then it flushes it.  The flushing is what allows you to see the results right away.  You can call flush manually without the newline, like this:

```
logfile.flush();
```

Also, when you call GetAsyncKeyState, you should filter out everything but the most significant bit, like this:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState('A') & 0x8000)
```

Read the docs under 'Return value' to understand why: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx